# XwalkView doesn't load file

Tags: android, webview, crosswalk

I'm using the latest stable xwalkview version. It worked well, but not working on Xiaomi devices.

```
06-14 13:57:17.709 17493-17750/com.james.lanbook E/art:      dlopen("/data/data/com.james.xxxxxx/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so", RTLD_LAZY) failed: dlopen failed: library "/data/data/com.james.xxxxxxx/app_xwalkcore/libxwalkcore.so" not found
```

[App Version] build:18.48.477.13, api:5, min_api:1

[Lib Version] build:18.48.477.13, api:5, min_api:5

Comment: I'm having the same problem here , did you find any fix ?

Comment: no( it doesn't work Xiaomi